# MAMP,Wordpress and Mavericks bug?

Tags: wordpress, mamp, osx-mavericks

I had several local developments going and prior to my upgrade everything was working seamless. I am now facing the white screen of death in WordPress, the theme that I'm working on displays but I cannot login to the backend for necessary changes. Any suggestions on what steps to take?

Answer (score 1):

Check your php error logs, they should be found at `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`.

Comment: Thank you. I found the answers. Had to reset some config settings and rename some of my theme ...got them working. Call thank you